# curl code incomplete or not working

Tags: curl, referer

I am using this code:

```
<?php
 error_reporting(E_ALL);
 $ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.csservers.ro/voteaza/cs.mnx.ro');
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://www.csservers.ro/evidenta/cs.mnx.ro');
 $html = curl_exec($ch);
 curl_close($ch);
 echo $html;
?>
```

The end result should be "Ip-ul sau clasa asta a mai votata odata ! Incearca maine !"
or "Se accepta doar voturi din Romania si Republica Moldova" but i get displayed just an empty rectangle. 
Also the acces on that url should record my ip. Does curl block that ? 
Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.64 Safari/537.11');
```

and now html ends with

```
<p>Se accepta doar voturi din Romania si Republica Moldova </p>
```

Comment: thats one step ahead , but it doesnt show corectly for everyone.

Comment: for me its just showing  'Ip-ul sau clasa asta a mai votata odata ! Incearca maine !'